# Extracting XML from webBrowser Control

Tags: c#, xml, browser

I am looking to parse the XML itself from a webBrowser control.

I have tried using `webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString()` to get the XML but it doesn't give the XML itself, it gives the web page source with all the css, etc which provides the page. An example of this is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
  <example>Hello</example>
</test>
```

That is what I want to have in the output but instead doing `webBrowser.DocumentText.ToString()` gives the following:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<STYLE>BODY{font:x-small 'Verdana';margin-right:1.5em}
.c{cursor:hand}
.b{color:red;font-family:'Courier New';font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none}
.e{margin-left:1em;text-indent:-1em;margin-right:1em}
.k{margin-left:1em;text-indent:-1em;margin-right:1em}
.t{color:#990000}
.xt{color:#990099}
.ns{color:red}
.dt{color:green}
.m{color:blue}
.tx{font-weight:bold}
.db{text-indent:0px;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em;border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;font:small Courier}
.di{font:small Courier}
.d{color:blue}
.pi{color:blue}
.cb{text-indent:0px;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em;font:small Courier;color:#888888}
.ci{font:small Courier;color:#888888}
PRE{margin:0px;display:inline}</STYLE>
<SCRIPT><!--
function f(e){
if (e.className=="ci"){if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"cb");}
if (e.className=="di"){if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"db");}
e.id="";
}
function fix(e,cl){
e.className=cl;
e.style.display="block";
j=e.parentElement.children(0);
j.className="c";
k=j.children(0);
k.style.visibility="visible";
k.href="#";
}
function ch(e){
mark=e.children(0).children(0);
if (mark.innerText=="+"){
mark.innerText="-";
for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++)
e.children(i).style.display="block";
}
else if (mark.innerText=="-"){
mark.innerText="+";
for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++)
e.children(i).style.display="none";
}}
function ch2(e){
mark=e.children(0).children(0);
contents=e.children(1);
if (mark.innerText=="+"){
mark.innerText="-";
if (contents.className=="db"||contents.className=="cb")
contents.style.display="block";
else contents.style.display="inline";
}
else if (mark.innerText=="-"){
mark.innerText="+";
contents.style.display="none";
}}
function cl(){
e=window.event.srcElement;
if (e.className!="c"){e=e.parentElement;if (e.className!="c"){return;}}
e=e.parentElement;
if (e.className=="e") ch(e);
if (e.className=="k") ch2(e);
}
function ex(){}
function h(){window.status=" ";}
document.onclick=cl;
--></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY class="st"><DIV class="e">
<SPAN class="b">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<SPAN class="m">&lt;?</SPAN><SPAN class="pi">xml version="1.0" </SPAN><SPAN class="m">?&gt;</SPAN>
</DIV>
<DIV class="e">
<DIV class="c" STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em"><A href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()" class="b">-</A>
<SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class="t">test</SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV><DIV class="e"><DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
<SPAN class="b">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN class="t">example</SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN><SPAN class="tx">Hello</SPAN><SPAN class="m">&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN class="t">example</SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN>
</DIV></DIV>
<DIV><SPAN class="b">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<SPAN class="m">&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN class="t">test</SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
</DIV></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I get the XML itself from a web browser control? The XML file I am trying to parse displays information about a user and it requires cookies. The user previously logs in before the application trys to get this information so the cookies are set in the webBrowser control. I have tried using `Xml.Load()` but that doesn't allow you to use a CookieContainer as far as I know, I have also tried using a HttpWebRequest with a CookieContainer but I am having trouble setting the cookies from the webBrowser into the CookieContainer.

If anyone has a way I can load the XML itself from the web browser control or a solution to using cookies from a web browser control in a CookieContainer I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following, that will get you cookies.

```
webBrowser1.Document.Cookie
```

And add it to cookie container as shown below.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(myUri, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have tried this previously. I may be doing it wrong though, do you know if the Uri has to be in a certain format? Previously I was using the URL to which I was making the web request to.

Comment: Or else you can use an API called InternetGetCookie which you will get from pinvoke.